# Do "wizard-born" individuals exist (legally speaking) in the Muggle world?

Tags: harry-potter, wizards, muggles

If a Witch or a Wizard is Muggle-born they most certainly exist in a legal sense as Muggle citizens (i.e. they have birth records, school records, national insurance number, IDs and so on).

It is also not impossible that at least some half-bloods (the ones with one Muggle parent) have this kind of dual identity.

But what about pure-bloods and Wizard-borns in general? They are presumably born at St. Mungo's so that means no (Muggle) birth certificate, no citizenship and no ID (it also means no taxes now that I think about it :D). So, they are  for all intents and purposes illegal immigrants.

I realize that most wizards have little to no contact with Muggle world if they can help it, but at least some of them (Arabella Figg - yes, she's a Squib but still an outsider) live there.

So what happens if a wizard (say upon entering the King's Cross) is stopped by a Police Officer and asked for an ID? Not everybody knows how to cast Obliviate or to Disapparate.

Comment: There's no legal requirement to carry ID on you in most situations, so simply saying "I don't have any on me." would be sufficient if you were stopped.

Comment: Ok. But my main question was if "wizard-borns" exist as citizens of Muggle UK as well or just as members of Wizarding Britain?

Comment: I fail to see why being born at St. Mungo's would preclude non-magical documentation of birth in the first place.  Wizards can fill out paperwork better than Muggles can, after all.

Comment: Because St. Mungo's doesn't exist as far as Muggles are concerned. Because I don't see a typical pureblood family registering their kid at Muggle Register office or even knowing that they should. Besides, how can one register their child if /they/ don't exist according to the (muggle) records?

Comment: I deleted Snape from your list of people who live in Muggle world. I don't think there's any evidence in canon that he does?

Comment: @DVK: Do you consider Harry Potter Lexicon a reliable source of canon info? if so then Snape _does_ live in the Muggle city. We can see that in Ch2 of HBP: find "SNAPE at HOME" http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/snape.html

Comment: @fen not unless lexicon references a quote from book or interview

Comment: @DVK Look up Ch2 of HBP "Spinner's End" : "Side by side they stood looking across the road at the rows and rows of dilapidated brick houses, their windows dull and blind in the darkness. “He lives here?” asked Bella in a voice of contempt. “Here? In **this Muggle dunghill?** We must be the first of our kind ever to set foot —”"                   as well as                                                     "... saw Narcissa darting through an alley between the houses into a second, almost identical street. Some of **the streetlamps** were broken;"

Comment: There's also the little matter of Ron getting a driving license in the epilogue of *Deathly Hallows*. That's tough to do without proof of age.

Comment: @StanRogers [Related](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/107091/31394).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's really no explicit canon answer I'm aware of (in books/interviews), but all the clues point to the fact that this is at best, extremely rare, aside from the times when it's preferable to do so for practical necessities.

- One example when it was likely done would be Kingsley's muggle position as secretary to PM; it may have required some documents etc..., and it would probably be easier to trick Muggles to issue them than to struggle with payroll systems ADP-magic. COBOL is like Hagrid, very magic resistant.
- Another one would be, as you pointed out, Squibs - they wouldn't be able to survive in Muggle world otherwise.

This is why Ministry of Magic has people set to deal with Muggles, post-factum, who will MIB-style flashy-thingy everyone via obliviate, conofound etc...

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I mean, there just /has/ to be some sort of service that helps Wizards/Squibs to "blend in". Probably that Muggle Relations job mentioned in OotP...

Comment: But as SEEN IN THE FILMS, Ministry people like Mr. Weasley operate poorly in common muggle situations, like the underground or understanding the function of a rubber duck. Muggle studies at Hogwarts or at the Ministry indicates to me that witches and wizards are muggle-clueless. Most don't try to pass or interact in our world even though the PM does get involved on occasion.

Comment: Another example would be to pay taxes; as you yourself have summed that they may need to: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54038/do-wizards-pay-muggle-taxes?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

The Muggle Prime minister (their newspapers, in fact) acknowledges the deaths of Madam Amelia Bones and Emmeline Vance as those of "a middle-aged woman who lived alone" and one who "lived in the backyards of the ministry" respectively, and the latter in particular, seem to presuppose a Muggle identity. This may have even been typical of well employed (in the magical world) wizards and witches to live with Muggle identities in Muggle surroundings, but as lone retired people. But there seems to be no canon evidence as to whether Bones and Vance were pure-bloods or not.

Comment: I would assume that many Squibs live in the Muggle world.