# How are Muggle-borns and possibly half-bloods not missed at public school?

Tags: harry-potter

Wouldn't the British Parliament wonder where the Muggle-borns students who were supposed to attend their school have gone to?

Or at least, question their parents about their children's whereabouts? And when the child returns home to the Muggle world in the summer, question the children themselves?

Wouldn't they or shouldn't they have been able to intercept at least one letter of invitation and acceptance to a Wizarding School like Hogwarts from like, an owl?

Or better yet, why didn't this guard report to the public that Harry and Ron attempted to go through a platform before flying the **Ford Anglia** and were witnessed by no less than seven muggles (*Chamber of Secrets*), and possibly questioned both of them at the end of the second year?

Or even better, question everybody else that seems to enter and/or leave **Platform 9 3/4** for whatever levels of intents and purposes?

Comment: Easy way to solve it: "Oh Timmy was given a scholarship to a private school"

Comment: *How are muggle-borns and possibly half-bloods not missed at public school?* - Very well, thank you.

Comment: Also related: [Do “wizard-born” individuals exist (legally speaking) in the Muggle world?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36659/21267)

Answer (score 5):

The Ministry of Magic, and in particular, the Minister of Magic, reports directly to the muggle Prime Minister.

That is to say, elements of the British Parliament are fully aware of the Wizarding World.  They probably help cover up some of the things Moldeyvort does.

> “The Prime Minister gazed hopelessly at the pair of them for a moment, then the words he had fought to suppress all evening burst from him at last.
>
> “But for heaven’s sake — you’re wizards! You can do magic! Surely you can sort out — well — anything!”
>
> Scrimgeour turned slowly on the spot and exchanged an incredulous look with Fudge, who really did manage a smile this time as he said kindly, “The trouble is, the other side can do magic too, Prime Minister.”
>
> ― J.K. Rowling, *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

From this we can derive that when a child Wizard is identified by the Ministry as such and sends the invitation to Hogwarts, the U.K. govt is informed and said child's public record is quietly updated.

Other countries probably have similar systems.